# Cannot use ffmepg on Clipgrab Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ffmpeg

I have Clipbgrab on my Ubuntu 12.10, but when I download on mp3 mode it doesnt convert the video on mp3 file. Do you know how can I upgrade to a new version to use it?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-convert-youtube-video-to-mp3-on-line-with-a-command-line-script-

**HOWTO: Easily enable MP3, MPEG4, AAC, and other restricted encoders in FFmpeg**

A common question is "why doesn't the repository FFmpeg convert to mp3, aac, mpeg4, etc?". Ubuntu doesn't make it very clear to the general user why the repository FFmpeg is limited or how to fix this issue. This is reflected in the number of forum questions relating to this topic.

Why is FFmpeg from the repository so limited?
All application software Ubuntu installs by default must be considered free, but Ubuntu views some encoders and formats to be proprietary or commercial. Users must install these packages on their own. See the Ubuntu Licensing Policy for more details.

C. **Medibuntu (Ubuntu 12.04 precise LTS)**
Medibuntu is a third-party repository that contains packages that are unable to be included in the official Ubuntu repositories. To install FFmpeg from Medibuntu open Terminal (Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal) and run the following:

```
sudo -E wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

Medibuntu’s repository is deactivated by upgrading to a newer Ubuntu release, so you should run this command again after the release upgrade.

Now you may also wish to add the following packages. The first (APP-INSTALL-DATA-MEDIBUNTU) will cause many apps from the Medibuntu repository to appear in Ubuntu Software Center (Ubuntu 9.10+) or Add/Remove Applications (versions prior to 9.10). The second will allow users to generate crash reports against Medibuntu packages and submit them to the Medibuntu bugtracker.

```
sudo apt-get install app-install-data-medibuntu apport-hooks-medibuntu
```

Now install libavcodec:
Code:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
```

Code:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

That's it. Now you have a non-crippled version of FFmpeg.

Comment: You copied parts from a blog article that copied parts from a post on ubuntuforums.org. The post was removed from the forums because Ubuntu switched from FFmpeg to a fork and due to the new, strict post editing policy at the forums. It's funny how this stuff circulates.